# Edit text to Spinner - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner, android-spinner, android-database

I have 3 activities.

In the first activity, I can edit 4 string type values which are saved in a database.userid,name and phone.

The idea is that a userid can be used multiple times.

So if i give the value userid the string "James" multiple times,in the 2nd Activity i can type in an edit text the string "james" and every value from my database has as userid string "James" will appear in a spinner

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public DBHelper helper;
public ArrayList<String> theList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    String input =((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString();
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    helper = new DBHelper(SecondActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    theList = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{DBHelper.FIELD_4}, DBHelper.FIELD_1+"=?", new String[]{input}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            theList.add(cursor.getString(4));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SecondActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, theList);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}
```

}

That is my code so far and I thought it would work but it doesn't.

**NOTE**: I can't use raw queries

Answer (score 0):

Your code of searching database seems OK, but you need to make sure of:

1. You searched the database with the value of the `EditText` String in `onCreate()` without giving a change to the user to input their text in the `EditText`; so if you didn't set a value to this `EditText` in `XML` layout, then `input` will contain an empty `String` resulting in an empty list in the `Spinner`
2. Make sure not to use abstract numbers in queries and use the final values; so you would change:

```
theList.add(cursor.getString(4));
```

into

```
theList.add(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.FIELD_4));
```

Also you can try to match your query with `LIKE` and remove the selection arguments as an alternative solution

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, 
                                new String[]{DBHelper.FIELD_4},  // columns to return (projection)
                                DBHelper.FIELD_1 + " LIKE '%" + input + "%' " // selection
                                null,  // selection args
                                null, null, null);
```

Comment: i just changed to theList.add(cursor.getString(4)); to theList.add(cursor.getString(0)); and it seemed to be working as i wanted it to.Don't really understood why,but it's fine for now

Comment: @DimitrisSioutis good to know .. thanks to accept the answer if it helped you solve your issue